# Resizing images on page

Tags: block-editor, images

I'm having problems resizing a lot of the pictures in my page.

For instance, using a "cover" image lets me resize the width but the height remains the same, no matter what I do.

I have tried the following things:

1. Picking a picture that has a small height (about 200 px)
2. Uploading a new image and then cropping it to the desired height in the “Edit Media” options

Both of these result in a picture that’s the same height as the default picture. It just zooms in more.

[image]

I also tried using the "Media and Text" block, but the same problem happens. Even if I upload a super small picture, it automatically resizes it to be the default size.

[image]

If it helps, I'm using the Ixion theme.

Comment: You can use add_image_size function.

Comment: @Bapi I don't know what that means. What function? Where do I find that? I'm using wordpress.com so I don't have any actual code that I'm writing.